# ASP Calendar double click event get the date of clicked day

Tags: development, asp.net

I haw got the ASP Calendar. I want to choose range from date to date. If i choose "SelectionChanged" i could only set one date. I think meybe I could set a second date which is end of Date Rannge when I double cliced on Calendar, but how could I do it. Please help me.

**Solution:**

I done this, by OnSelected Event, and this code:

`if (TextBox5.Text == "") { this.TextBox5.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString(); this.TextBox6.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString(); }`

Comment: I done this, by OnSelected Event, and this code:
`   if (TextBox5.Text == "")
            {
                this.TextBox5.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
                this.TextBox6.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
            }`

Comment: You can add this code to your question by editing it.